# Find word into cell

Tags: vba, excel

Excel - VBA
I was wondering how to find a word into a Excel range of rows using VBA. Ex. "word to be found", this is not just the cell value but a word into a string. For instance, the way to find the word "network" into the string "Need help to map network printer".

```
Sub SearchForSfb()

   Dim LSearchRow As Integer
   Dim LCopyToRow As Integer

   On Error GoTo Err_Execute

   'Start search in row 1
   LSearchRow = 1

   'Start copying data to row 2 in Open (row counter variable)
   LCopyToRow = 2

   While Len(Range("E" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value) > 0

      'If value in column E = "word to be found", copy entire row to Open
      If Range("E" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value = "word to be found" Then

         'Select row in Data to copy
         Rows(CStr(LSearchRow) & ":" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Select
         Selection.Copy

         'Paste row into SFB in next row
         Sheets("SFB").Select
         Rows(CStr(LCopyToRow) & ":" & CStr(LCopyToRow)).Select
         Sheets("SFB").Paste

         'Move counter to next row
         LCopyToRow = LCopyToRow + 1

         'Go back to Data to continue searching
         Sheets("Data").Select

      End If

      LSearchRow = LSearchRow + 1

   Wend

   'Position on cell A3
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
   Range("A3").Select

   MsgBox "All matching data has been copied."

   Exit Sub

Err_Execute:
   MsgBox "An error occurred."

End Sub
```

Comment: see [Count keywords within phrases](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32860792/count-keywords-within-phrases/32878493#32878493)

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple loop

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim lstRw As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim s As String
    Dim c As Range

    s = "* network *"

    Set ws = Sheets("Data")
    Set sh = Sheets("SFB")

    With ws
        lstRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng = .Range("E2:E" & lstRw)
    End With

    For Each c In rng.Cells
        If c.Value Like s Then
            c.EntireRow.Copy sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        End If
    Next c


End Sub
```

Or you can use a filter macro

```
Sub FiltExample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, sh As Worksheet
    Dim rws As Long, rng As Range
    Set ws = Sheets("Data")
    Set sh = Sheets("SFB")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = 0

    With ws
        rws = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("E:E").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*network*"
        Set rng = .Range("A2:Z" & rws).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        rng.EntireRow.Copy sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, from your code I will use "s" variable part to use it in my VBA, it works nicely. `'Word to look up s = "*SFB *"
'If value in column E = "word to be found", copy entire row to Open If Range("E" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value Like s Then` Thx