# How to sift through a filtered range to see if any cells contain certain text

Tags: excel, vba

Every part of my code works thus far, I just want to edit one part. I have my macro searching through a filtered range to see if it contains "CHECKED IN" and "CHECKED OUT".

However I want to add many more words to check for. Is there any way I can change this code to perhaps make an array of strings that each cell is searched for?

I suppose I can add a lot of "if or"s, but that isn't fun.

```
Sub checkk()
Dim cl As Range, rng As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim celltxt As String
Dim i As Integer

i = 1

With ActiveSheet
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With

Set rng = Range("A1:A" & LastRow)

For Each cl In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
cl.Select
celltxt = ActiveCell.Text
If InStr(1, celltxt, "CHECKED OUT") Or InStr(1, celltxt, "CHECKED IN") Then
MsgBox ("found it")
else
MsgBox ("no")
End If



Next cl

If i > 1 Then
MsgBox ("Looks like you have to do some more filtering, sort column A by 
color to see what was tagged")

End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count and Highlight keywords within phrases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32860792/count-and-highlight-keywords-within-phrases) and/or [Pattern matching in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32946884/pattern-matching-in-excel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes of course you can create array and loop through array

```
Sub checkk()
    Dim cl As Range, rng As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim celltxt As String
    Dim arrVarToCheck(2) As Variant

    arrVarToCheck(0) = "CHECKED OUT"
    arrVarToCheck(1) = "CHECKED IN"
    arrVarToCheck(2) = "Foo"

    With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    Set rng = Range("A1:A" & LastRow)

    For Each cl In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        celltxt = cl.Text
        For i = 0 To UBound(arrVarToCheck)
            If InStr(1, celltxt, arrVarToCheck(i)) Then
                MsgBox ("found it")
            Else
                MsgBox ("no")
            End If
        Next i
    Next cl
End Sub
```