# Excel highlight part of text in cell that differs from other cell

Tags: excel

It there a way to achieve something like this in Excel:

[image]

I am looking for way to highlight part of text in cell that differs from other cell. Difference can appear at any position in cell.

Comment: I do not think that it is possible.

Comment: You'll need VBA for this. Use the `Characters` collection to change the formatting of part of the text.

Comment: You may be interested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32860792/count-and-highlight-keywords-within-phrases/32878493#32878493.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this sub procedure.

```
Sub Macro5()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, p As Long, arr1 As Variant, arr2 As Variant

    With Worksheets("sheet4")
        For i = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
            'remove previous character formatting
            .Cells(i, "A") = .Cells(i, "A").Value2
            .Cells(i, "B") = .Cells(i, "B").Value2

            'split cell values into arrays on a 'pipe' delimiter
            arr1 = Split(.Cells(i, "A").Value2, Chr(124))
            arr2 = Split(.Cells(i, "B").Value2, Chr(124))

            'found in column A; not found in column B
            For j = LBound(arr1) To UBound(arr1)
                If IsError(Application.Match(arr1(j), arr2, 0)) Then
                    p = InStr(1, .Cells(i, "A").Value2, arr1(j), vbTextCompare)
                    With .Cells(i, "A").Characters(Start:=p, Length:=Len(arr1(j))).Font
                        .Bold = True
                        .Color = vbRed
                    End With
                End If
            Next j

            'found in column B; not found in column A
            For j = LBound(arr2) To UBound(arr2)
                If IsError(Application.Match(arr2(j), arr1, 0)) Then
                    p = InStr(1, .Cells(i, "B").Value2, arr2(j), vbTextCompare)
                    With .Cells(i, "B").Characters(Start:=p, Length:=Len(arr2(j))).Font
                        .Bold = True
                        .Color = vbRed
                    End With
                End If
            Next j
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: It worked fine. I have placed it as new module and executed it. I've noticed that when I run macro for the first time it creates correct results but when I run it again on already highlighted cells, then it adds additional colors. Unfortunately I have very little knowledge about VBA/macros but this solution is encouraging to learn more. Many thanks for support!

Comment: I forgot to mention that the oryginal input value for this task looked like that:

"CAN|DEU|MEX|USA|VNM || CAN|DEU|GBR|MEX|USA"

It was in one cell, and values to compare were separated by space-pipe-pipe-space. I have used formula in Excel to split one cell into two cells based on " || " separator. Can this macro be modified to work on oryginal values in one cell?

Comment: I suppose you could dim another variant and use that to split on a double pipe. Then each element would be column A or B as the case may be. Getting p from the original isn't an issue since each would be missing from the other.